# Scala spark-shell: schema function structType type mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Learning scala to work with spark and having difficulty with return types:

Code:

```
def createSchema (name: String) : StructType = {
  if (name == "test01") {
    StructType(
      List(
        StructField("id", StringType, true),
        StructField("score", DoubleType, true)
  ))}
}
```

Produces:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
```

Without the argument and if condition the function works as expected.

Understand the `if` condition is the last evaluated expression and is setting the return type to `Unit`.

Have tried `val` definition (and other variations) without success.

Code:

```
def createSchema (name: String) : StructType = {
  val struct: StructType = if (name == "test01") {
    StructType(
      List(
        StructField("id", StringType, true),
        StructField("score", DoubleType, true)
  ))}
  struct
}
```

Produces:

```
error: type mismatch; 
found   : Unit
required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
var struct: StructType = if (name == "test01") {
                         ^
```

Appreciate any help understanding the type mismatch errors and solutions.

Solution for testing function using if (as learning exercise).

Code:

```
def createSchema (name: String) : StructType = {
  val struct = if (name == "test01") {
    StructType(
      List(
        StructField("id", StringType, true),
        StructField("score", DoubleType, true)
    ))
  }
  else {
    StructType(
      List(
        StructField("col1", StringType, true),
        StructField("col2", StringType, true)
    ))
  }
  struct
}
```

Thanks for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not defined an else condition, it returns the smallest common super type for all branches, which is `Unit`. Keep in mind that the if condition could also not be true which means the body of your method is empty (= Unit).

You could verify this by typing in

```scala
val struct = if (name == "test01") {
  StructType(
    List(
      StructField("id", StringType, true),
      StructField("score", DoubleType, true)
    )
  )
}
```

into your Scala REPL to see that is retuns:

```sh
struct: Any = ()
```

Declare an else condition or, as you have done it, remove the if condition.